# What’s the smallest known sha256 hash that was ever produced?

Tags: hash, sha-256, rainbow-table

Basically the same question as [this one](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/65478/which-is-the-smallest-hash-that-has-ever-been-hashed), except in my case the value to be hashed doesn’t have to be a valid Bitcoin block, but is a bytearray of arbitrary length and content (and that my use case is completely unrelated to Bitcoin).

In details, I have to deal with a computation that does `x^ ((Integer)sha256(y)&0x7ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff000)`, and while I know it’s impossible to have a value of `bytearray y` that yield the smallest possible number in order to get a computable result, I’m nevertheless still curious in knowing the smallest value of `sha256` ever found…
As it’s arbitrary data, I suppose the smallest value ever found is lower than the smallest  hash value of a Bitcoin block ever found. **Bitcoin hashes are `sha256(sha256(80 Bytes))`** but in my case even 0 bytes is acceptable.

Comment: I don't think this question and its answer are useful to any of us. Why do you need to know it? What is the aim here? Besides, the nonce of the Bitcoin is already makes it almost random input...

Comment: @kelalaka I'm interested.

Comment: I don't think this is a question that, in the general case, is answerable.  It could have occurred, just by happenstance, that the SHA-256 value used in HKDF in one of my random TLS connections was the smallest ever, and nobody would ever have recorded that fact.  (And, due to forward secrecy, we'd never be able to recompute it efficiently.)  In order to know this, you'd have to have recorded every hash ever produced, and we haven't.

Comment: IMO, This question is not well-formed, because you're presuming that every hash that's ever been produced has been _logged_ somewhere or is somehow retrievable. I've produced many hashes down in my basement with the lights off --- and until now, I haven't told a soul! Just last week, I produced the lowest _possible_ hash. No cheating, I swear!

Comment: I still don't get what this is actually asking for; the recent edits seem to rule out the existing, at least somewhat generally informative answers. Yet knowing that the "current lowest" sha256 
 hash is 42, 0, or 4335069948445692188679829484389622911617539336091310364 tells you nothing at all, but apparently that's what is being asked for, isn't it?

Answer (score 10):

We can almost certainly say the hash corresponding to the Bitcoin block [756951](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/block/756951) (which was mined on 2022-10-04 01:28 UTC) is the smallest SHA-256 hash that has ever been produced:

```
0000000000000000000000005d6f06154c8685146aa7bc3dc9843876c9cefd0f
```

This hash starts with an incredible 97 binary zeros. If you would like to find another hash which starts with that many zeros - you would have to calculate about 1.5845632502852868e+29 (2^97) hashes to achieve a 50% probability of finding one. That's thousands of times more than the estimated number of drops of water on earth.

Bitcoin miners are calculating many orders of magnitude more hashes then anyone else who uses SHA-256 for any purpose combined - therefore, they are the most likely ones to produce a really small hash.
Currently, all Bitcoin miners combined are calculating about 67 times more hashes than there are grains of sand on Earth, every single second.

**Note:** I've found this hash by writing a Rust program which downloaded the data from https://gz.blockchair.com/bitcoin/blocks/ and searched the files for the lowest hash.

Comment: Imagine if all that compute power went to something like protein folding or understanding prime numbers better!

Comment: @qwr we re talking about asics. If ypu want produce an uupgrade of twirl that can be implemented on fpgas, I m all in.

Comment: Such a hash has 1/(10^100) probability that shows the power of the bitcoin miners. now that reached 2^93 in a year

Comment: Where might one get the data whose hash is this value?  I don't do cryptocurrency stuff so wouldn't know.

Comment: @Myria I'm not actually sure, but perhaps this might be helpful:
https://medium.com/hackergirl/how-to-calculate-the-hash-of-a-block-in-bitcoin-8f6aebb0dc6d

Comment: @qwr IIRC the economics of crypto mining mean that mining power *must* be wasted for it to work properly. If you'd use protein folding, then people who actually need proteins folded would have an unfair advantage because they could get free bitcoins in the course of their normal work. This angers crypto-anarchists, who strongly believe that only rich investors, not biologists, should get free money.

Comment: @user253751 Yeah, it's absurd what Bitcoin (community) turned into. IMO the point of PoW is not to "convert" energy into bitcoins, but to assure 1 party can't control all of the block production and to make distribution of coins fair. Cardano has achieved that with PoS. And with like thousands of times less wasted energy. PoS is letting math fairly select the next block producer weighted by their stake and PoW is everyone doing useless bs to prove they are rich and powerful enough to be the next block producer. It's absurd.

Comment: @TypicalHog There are many blockchains with proof-of-stake. The most well-known one would be Ethereum. In fact it's probably the majority of them, since IIRC there can only be one successful PoW chain in a stable equilibrium under certain conditions. I take it that you are personally invested in Cardano and that's why you're advertising it here.

Comment: @user253751 Ofc I'm going to be "advertising" Cardano since I'm convinced it's the best. It makes sense I'm invested in something I think is the best. I also "advertise" Rust lang cause I think it's the best. Ethereum's PoS is a joke. It has locking, only rich can afford to particiapate, it's custodial, you can lose staked coins, all of this causes low participation rate, only like a few entities control more than 50% of the block production while in Cardano that number is like 35. Even Coinbase and Binance combined have only like 13%. So, yes I do believe Cardano has the best PoS out there.

Comment: “This hash starts with an incredible 96 binary zeros” — if this string is in base 16 and the 25-th symbol is $5_{16}=0101_2$, then it starts with $24\times4+1=97$ binary zeros.

Comment: @lyricallywicked You are right! My mistake! I fixed it!

Comment: This is a SHA256d hash, that is the SHA-256 of a SHA-256. I agree it's extremely likely this is the smallest SHA256d ever produced. But there's no reason to rule out that an even smaller intermediary hash was computed, and immediately forgotten. Thus I'd say this very likely is the smallest SHA-256 known, and there's a nearly 50% chances this is the smallest SHA-256 ever produced.

Comment: @fgrieu-modelectiontime That's actually true! This went completely over my head.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR**

*Let's try to estimate this, based on some purported data [if someone has better data they can make the estimate better as well].*

*There is a claim I read somewhere, that I can't find a link to, that there were 200 quintillion SHA256 hashes computed in Bitcoin mining per second, sometime in the recent past.*

*If this is reasonable, then the minimum is about $2^{159}$ which is a 256 bit number with 97 leading zeroes.*

**Details:**

If you have data about how many in other applications, in case this is not negligible compared to Bitcoin computations, you can adjust.

We model the SHA256 output as being uniformly distributed on
$$
\{0,1,\ldots,M-1\}
$$
where $M=2^{256}.$ Assuming independence, if you have $n$ SHA outputs $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ then the minimum
$$Y=\min\{X_k:1\leq k\leq n\}$$
satisfies
$$
\textrm{Prob}\{Y > y\}=\left(\frac{M-y}{M}\right)^n.
$$
This means that if you want this probability to be say $2^{-k},$ then it can be computed by plugging in $M$ but you'll need to take logs and be careful.

If you're lazy and only want the expected minimum, you can find the CDF ${Prob}\{Y \leq y\},$ differentiate to get the density, and compute the expectation. See this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786392/expectation-of-minimum-of-n-i-i-d-uniform-random-variables) where this is detailed. If the distribution of the $X_i$ and $Y$ is projected on to the interval $[0,1)$ by dividing the hash output by $2^{256},$ and treating it as a real valued random variable, then the expectation is simply $\frac{1}{n+1},$ which is pleasing. Lifting back to $\{0,\ldots,M-1\}$ gives an expectation of the minimum being
$$
\frac{M}{n+1}.
$$
For 300 quintillion hashes per second (check my computations) I get
a hashrate of $2^{67}$ per second or $2^{92}$ per year. So using a year, we get the expected minimum $Y$ to be approximately
$$
\frac{2^{256}}{2^{97}}=2^{159},
$$
with 97 leading zeroes in its **binary** expansion.

Comment: https://ycharts.com/indicators/bitcoin_network_hash_rate says currently it's about 500M terahashes/sec, so 500 quintillion. So your number is the right order of magnitude.

Comment: The first order statistic over the standard uniform distribution has distribution Beta(1,n)

Comment: @kodlu **Bitcoin hashes are `sha256(sha256(80 Bytes))`** but in my case even 0 bytes is acceptable. So does the fact 130 times less effort is Ok doesn t change anything?

Comment: @user2284570, the *output* of the hash is modelled as a uniformly distributed element of $\{0,1\}^{256},$ which is independent of exactly what the input is--so no change to the argument is needed.

Comment: @kodlu but I m pointing what to hash is smaller and thus number of hashes per seconds can be greater.

Comment: @user2284570 SHA256 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4634 operates on 64-byte blocks. So the minimum effort is one block.

Comment: That certainly tallies with the other answer.

Comment: I do not understand. If $n=2^{92},$ why is $2^{97}$ in the denominator?